# C# SqlConnection failure

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I am experiencing the beauty of Sql database opening in Visual Studio
I am following an [example](http://www.ittutorialswithexample.com/2015/01/simple-windows-form-login-application-in-csharp.html) found on the web for building a login form. I created an mdf database and I am trying to connect it as following

```
private string _connectStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Mold Sentinel.mdf;Integrated Security=False;";
private SqlConnection  _sqlConn = null;
public frmLogIn()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  _sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_connectStr);
  try
  {
    _sqlConn.Open();
  }
  catch (SqlException ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Sql exception");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Exception");
  }
  return;
}
```

This does not work and an SQL exception is catched. Does the space in the name "Mold Sentinel.ndf" hurts? The mdf is found in the same directory of the .cs files but Visula studio (wisely?) make a copy of it in the release directory.

Comment: Show exception.

Comment: Id guess your datadirectory is not set to where the db is copied to

Comment: `Data Source(LocalDB)\v11.0` should be `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0`

Comment: For when you start writing your c# database code, please review [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements). Also `MessageBox.Show("Exception");` is a terrible idea, you are throwing away all the good information about the reason for the error like the type, the detailed message, the stack trace (what line caused the issue), and the inner exceptions.

Comment: What is the purpose of writing a try/catch block to show an useless message as "Exception"? . Remove the try catch and let the exception show itself, you should have enough informations to start your quest

Comment: Try to use `Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;`.

Comment: Yes, you must enclose the string in quotation marks if it contains spaces. `'Mold Sentinel.mdf';`

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your connection string!

Data Source(LocalDB)\v11.0; should be Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;

Hope this helps,
Good luck with your works!

Comment: OK I fixed the connection string as private string _connectStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\'Mold Sentinel.mdf';Integrated Security=False;"; but still does not help. I got a more weird error as https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3enscgkfl3ch00/Screenshot%202017-06-28%2014.14.14.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out the problem, which is my fault and I am sorry for wasting your time and effort: it was a bnaming issue: the db name was Modl Sentinel.mdf while I was trying to open Mold Sentinel.mdf ... thanks much to all (this was an useful traing for this: I am looking how to try/catch SQL related issues)